# data.table group by non-id column in joined table

Tags: r, data.table

Consider the following two data.tables:

```
x <- data.table(id=c(1,2,3,4),cost=c(0.7,0.2,0.5,0.9))
y <- data.table(id=c(1,2,3,4),group=c(1,2,1,2))
setkey(x,id)
setkey(y,id)
```

I would like to normalize cost by subtracting the mean, grouped by the group in y.

My attempt is as follows, however, R gives an error that it cannot find 'group':

```
x[y,cost:=(cost-mean(cost)),by=.(group)]
```

Is there a good way to perform this operation without adding a column to x?

Comment: What you wrote [*should* work](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1688), it just doesn't yet.

Comment: I guess for now you could do `x[y, group := i.group][, cost := cost - mean(cost), by = group]`. Or maybe this `x[y, cost := cost - ave(cost, i.group)]`

Comment: Thanks David, the latter seems to work well for me.

Comment: But keep in mind that it will be X4 slower than the former (I've just benchmarked)

Comment: So it looks like it answers the question, @DavidArenburg

Comment: @jangorecki OP asked for a way without creating a new column... While the `ave` solution is obviously not idiomatic as it is X4 times slower. As pointed by eddi, it seems like there is no solution currently.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
output <- y[x][, normcost:=(cost-mean(cost)), by=group]

output 
#    id group cost normcost
# 1:  1     1  0.7     0.10
# 2:  2     2  0.2    -0.35
# 3:  3     1  0.5    -0.10
# 4:  4     2  0.9     0.35
```